# YUI DIalog : how to stop form to be poster on enter key press?

Tags: forms, yui

We use YUI 2.9.0, and on a form we have a problem : if we press enter on an input type="text", the form is submitted the "normal way", and not via the async mode of YUI Dialog (the "normal way" is the one used in pure HTML web, without JS and web 2.0 asynchronous comm).

On this page I can see the bug was handled in version 2.3.1, but I still have one issue
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ydn-javascript/message/30139
In fact in depend of the content of the form : with a text and a select field I have the issue, if I had the datepicker it's run ok.

Is there any way, appart of key listerner wich stop enter key press?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can  shutdown form submissions on your dialog by putting this in the form tag:

```
<form onsubmit="return(false);" id="myId" name="myName" action="" method="">
```

you'll then have to put an event listener to your button or  do the XHR submission yourself .

althought if you use this declaration for your dialog with  isDefault set to true in handleSubmit you wouldnt probably  have the form submitted on enter keypress .

```
YAHOO.example.container.dialog1 = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog("dialog1", 
            { width : "300px",
              fixedcenter : true,
              visible : false, 
              constraintoviewport : true,
              buttons : [ { text:"Submit", handler:handleSubmit, isDefault:true },
                          { text:"Cancel", handler:handleCancel } ]
             } );
```

Comment: Great answer.  Note that you **do** need the empty `action` and `method` attributes.  My first (lazy) attempt used only the `onsubmit` attribute, and did not work.